# First list item (<li>) floating right in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am having problem with google chrome. The problem is the first list item's bullet is floating right while all other list item's bullet aligned correctly at left.

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="window_sub_title2">The Interface</div>          
 <ul>
     <li>Toolbox </li>
     <li>Context Menus </li>
     <li>Tool Options Bar </li>
     <li>Menu Bar </li>
     <li>Palette Well </li>
     <li>Rulers </li>
     <li>Guides and grid </li>
     <li>Navigating in Photoshop </li>
     <li>Shortcuts </li>
     <li>File  Browser </li>
 </ul>
```

This is how it looks in chrome : http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/4807767137/

Here is the actual [link](http://www.dreamcaptureanimation.com/test/courses.php).

Comment: Can you provide some sample code which demonstrates this behaviour?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This css solved the problem for me:

```
li {
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
li {
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to manually override all the defaults of spacing and padding of the bullets.

Answer (score 1):

The background for this can be found [here in the bug reports](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89829) with a test case [here](https://bug-89829-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=149192). It only happens if you have a `float:left` applied to the block. The recommended fix is to do `clear:left;`, but you may need to be careful with targeting so that you don't accidentally clear elements that aren't buggy (like menus).

Answer (score 0):

I have face this kind of problem. I fixed this by doing this. Please take a look the code style carefully. I hope it would help you.

```
<ul>
     <li>Toolbox </li><li>
         Context Menus</li><li>
         Tool Options Bar </li><li>
         Menu Bar </li><li>
         ------ 
        File  Browser </li>
 </ul>
```